# Subscribe to Events in Generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Generic class which is inherited from ObservableCollection.

I want to get the notifications in this class whenever some particular properties of my object in this collection changes, not add or remove object but edit/update object.

I have some carrier classes which will be passed as Type argument to this generic class. Upon changing property in these classes, I want to raise an event which will further be handled in this Generic class.

```
public class CustomCollectionGenericClass<T>:ObservableCollection
{
}

public class HelperClass
{
public string Name
{
       get{return _name;}
       set{_name=value;
          //raise some event which will be handled in custom collection class
          }
}
}
```

I have no idea how to subscribe and raise event in this case

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: You don't seem to have an instance of `RoutineClass`.

Comment: With your edit, it looks like a job for `INotifyPropertyChanged` (on `HelperClass`) and `BindingList<T>` (in place of `CustomCollectionGenericClass<T>`)

Comment: @MarcGravell I have done some research with your suggestion. First things first, it works exactly as I want them to, but there are lots of concerns about the performance of BindingList. Is there anything else which raised the object changes notification but also performs well.

Answer (score 2):

You can only subscribe to non-static events against instances of a class. You cannot subscribe to non-static events from a type.

In your case, what you could do is add a type constraint, making sure that the constraint enforces that event to be available on that class and then subscribe to the events of an instance:

```
public class GenClass<T> where T : RoutineClass
{
    public someMethod(T yourInstance)
    {
        yourInstance.EventToSubscribe += yourHandler;
    }
}
```

In this example, I have added a method which receives an instance, since you did not have an instance anywhere inside your generic class. This might not be what you need, but either way, you need an instance to be able to subscribe to events.

Some clarification: this applies when you have non-static events (as per your code). In case you have static events, you can subscribe to events against the type.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but in his code there is no static event, only instance events